# Angular $http.post of MVC action returns error data as HTML

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, exception

I'm trying to call an existing controller action with angular.

The js call is as follows

```
    $http.post("Delete", {
        Id: id
    }).success(function () {
        $scope.getPagedData();
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //TODO: data is the HTML of the "yellow screen"
    });
```

My controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Delete(Guid id)
    {
        throw new Exception("testing");
    }
```

Why is data not set to "testing" or something I can show the user?

Comment: Because the controller throws an exception instead of returning any data, what you see is as expected.

Comment: So there's no good way to throw an exception, and display it's message?  I have to return an object that's contains an errors property and in EVERY "success" callback, check if that contains an error??  That's just...stupid.

Comment: This is not stupid. If you are doing SOA, the service should throw 500 error if there is something going wrong. This is what SOA about. The API should carry both *http status* and *data*. You really don't want to return 200 even the API fails.

Comment: My point wasn't "that it's stupid it throws a 500", I'm all for that!  I think it's ridiculous, that the response data is html, and not something easily consumable by an ajax request.  The fact I need to use response.write to get clean data returned is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something...

I first created a JsonHandleErrorAttribute that I can mark on my controller (probably add this to the FilterConfig)

```
public class JsonHandleErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Write(filterContext.Exception.Message);
        response.StatusCode = 500;
        response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Because the StatusCode is not 2xx it still enters `.error()` in javascript.  And since I used response.Write to just print out the error message, I don't have all the extra HTML markup.